# php: Need explanation on creating a google calendar crawling cron job

Tags: php, cron, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

In essence it seems like I don't understand the proper process of authenticating a cron service.

What I am trying to do:
I want to collect all events in a google calendar and store it in a mysql database. Sounds simple, but I've spent hours today trying to figure this out and have only gotten confused.

I've tried running

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CalendarId}/events?key={PublicAPIaccessKey}

hoping that it would work since the calendar is open to read access for everyone.

The response was

"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."

So I went into Google Developer Console and enabled Google Calendar.

It still reports the same error.

Then I tried using the PHP library for Google OAuth (that is currently working for authenticating my users), but I don't have an access token and this is not a "client", but a "service" I am creating.

I have read up on Google Service Accounts. But I haven't found a resource that explains how I can use this account. It almost seemed as if I needed to set up billing and pay for using this account? Which is out of the question.

I am at a loss on how to proceed. I will continue to google and try to figure it out, but if someone can please explain this for me it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the steps on service account creation here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#create_the_service_account_and_its_credentials